# Public transport services during Christmas period in New Zealand

Tags: public-transport, new-zealand, public-holidays

I am arriving to New Zealand on 24th of December. Are there any issues with public transportation during the Christmas period that I should consider? I am especially interested in the bus timetables (are they same compared to non-holiday days)?

Comment: Which cities/towns will you be in during the Christmas period? They'll differ occasionally.

Comment: Coromandel, Rotorua and Auckland for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Zealand doesn't treat Christmas eve as a holiday, this year the 24th falls on a Monday so it should be service as normal. Unlike some countries, New Zealand in my experience does offer **some** form of public transport everyday of the year in the main 3 centers. Id suspect Dunedin and Hamilton would also.

**Auckland** I have only spent a short amount of time in Auckland and their public transport was a painful mess at the time. Apparently its better, I couldn't find a simple policy on the [maxx](http://www.maxx.co.nz) site. I did find some info about [train disruption](http://www.maxx.co.nz/info/service-updates/rail-network-closures-over-christmas-and-new-year-holiday-period.aspx) for a month starting December 20th which might be useful. I have checked a couple of [bus time tables](http://www.maxx.co.nz/media/4696/e14_botany_mission%20heights_july%202010%20web.pdf) for Auckland and at the bottom they have a Sunday / Public Holiday detailing the times for the route. but...

> Christmas and New Year
>   Over the Christmas and New Year period, some services may not operate. Please always check 
>   with MAXX before travelling over this time.

I can only find media releases for Christmas 2010 services.

**Christchurch**: [metro info](http://www.metroinfo.co.nz/info/Pages/PublicHolidayTimetables.aspx) has a very clear blanket policy for all services on all public holidays.

**Wellington**: the [metlink](http://www.metlink.org.nz/christmas-services-effective-from-25-december-2012/) site has a clear overview of Christmas services which start on the 25th, so again you will be fine at the very least on the 24th.

Comment: Should tickets be booked in advance or there will be no problems with buying on the spot?

Comment: For inner-city transport, buy on the spot.  Inter-city, you should be ok, but if you're on a schedule I'd book in advance.

Comment: Mark is correct. Auckland, Wellington and Christchurch all have different contactless travel cards (similar to the oyster card in London) that you can purchase. The fares are cheaper(I can't remember how much) so consider getting one of these if your in a city for an extended period.